# Using UnixSignal in Mono throws System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, docker, mono

I have a console app running .Net 4.6.1 on mono in a Docker Container and it runs  fine. When developing the app further I'm looking into responding to unix signals using the Nuget-package [Mono.Posix](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix-4.5/).

According to the [Mono documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/#operating-system-questions) it is recommended running the UnixSignal handling in a separate thread.

So I'm trying to do this like the code below:

```
public void Run()
{
    var signalHandler = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenToSignal));
    signalHandler.Start();
}

private void ListenToSignal()
{
    var signals = new List<UnixSignal>() {
        new UnixSignal (Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGHUP),
        new UnixSignal (Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGINT),
        new UnixSignal (Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGQUIT),
        new UnixSignal (Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGTERM)
    };

    int index = UnixSignal.WaitAny(signals.ToArray());
    var signal = signals[index].Signum;
    Console.WriteLine($"Terminate signal was called: {signal}");
}
```

When starting the application it throws a `ArgrumentException`:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to handle signal
>   Parameter name: signum   at Mono.Unix.UnixSignal..ctor (Signum signum)
>   <0x40433de0 + 0x00097> in :0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Unix.UnixSignal:.ctor
>   (Mono.Unix.Native.Signum)   at
>   MangoFareScrapingGenericClient.Scraping.ListenToSignal () <0x404339e0
>   + 0x00117> in :0   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object
>   state) <0x7f20f10b1010 + 0x00099> in :0   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x7f20f10af850 + 0x0016e> in :0   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x7f20f10af820 + 0x00020> in :0   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state)
>   <0x7f20f10af770 + 0x00059> in :0   at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () <0x7f20f10b11d0 +
>   0x0002e> in :0

If I look on Github for the specific [code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix/UnixSignal.cs) it looks like `signal_info` is a `IntPtr.Zero` which throws the exception.

```
public UnixSignal (Signum signum)
{
    this.signum = NativeConvert.FromSignum (signum);
    this.signal_info = install (this.signum);
    if (this.signal_info == IntPtr.Zero) {
        throw new ArgumentException ("Unable to handle signal", "signum");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` support was added to Docker in ~2013 (I remember the pull-request because I needed that support in a deployment)

So I'm **assuming** either `SIGQUIT` or `SIGHUP` is failing to be installed.

**But**, since you did not say which signal is returning a `IntPtr.Zero` and thus throwing the exception, I would try installing *each* signal on its own to find the one that is not supported in your Ubuntu Docker environment.

At that point, you can test that signal under a straight `C` program to determine if it runs ok as it might be a problem in the `Mono` runtime running under Docker.

Plus you can try/catch your `UnixSignal.WaitAny` and gracefully degrade your signal processing and write a log message about the offending signal.

Comment: Thank you, I will test! Do you have a clue why a certain Signal is not available in my container? I'm using the latest from the official Mono/Xamarin image.

Comment: @Merryweather N clue.., it could be a Docker issue, a Mono issue, Docker on Ubuntu, etc... test them all out one by one and see what you get, update your question (or post another)... ;-)

Comment: @Merryweather I know that those signals within Mono run fine on Ubuntu (non-docker), OS-X, various Debian distos, etc... so again I am assuming it is something related to Docker that is not allowing that signal to be installed...

Comment: Thanks for the help @SushiHangover. It seems like `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` is not supported. The rest of them are, so I guess that is good enough.